# Counting no of columns in an android sqlite table

Tags: android

Hi i wants to count the total number of columns in android sqlite  table, please guide that how to achieve? what i tried is below

```
    public int numberOfColumns(String tableName) {


    Cursor cursor = database.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
            return cursor.getColumnCount();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

this works fine, what i wants to know is about it is, this approach is fine or anything better i can do!!
i visited lot of stackoverflow links but still have confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. There are some other methods such as `PRAGMA table_info(tablename)` but they aren't really that much better.

Checking for `cursor != null` is not necessary.

Also, it's a good idea to close your cursor before exiting the method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your cursor after leaving the function, this change should work (not tested)

```
public int numberOfColumns(String tableName) {
    int result = 0;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = database.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        result = cursor.getColumnCount();
        if (result < 0) {
            result = 0;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can't we just do this 
return db.query(dbTableName,null,null,null,null,null,null).getColumnCount();?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that if the column doesn't exist getColumnCount() will return -1. Based on @Jitesh question, numberOfColumns should return >=0 values